# websocket-rails: Cannot connect websocket

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, websocket-rails

I must be missing some important information about using websocket-rails, because I can't figure out how to connect to the websocket server. After running websocket_rails:install and following the guide, I get the following:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:3000/websocket.
```

Originally, checking in chrome it's clear it's a 404 error, meaning the address doesn't exist. The guide doesn't mention having to do any routing, so I have no idea how to fix this.

However, if I don't have any websocket controllers, then it becomes a handshake timeout, and switching to faye-websocket 0.10.0 doesn't fix the problem (as suggested [here](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/379)). I think there might be some kind of caching getting in the way, since any time I changed the websocket controller I would get an uninitialized constant error referencing the old name of the class, which no longer exists.

I've found the file in the library where the routing happens, so I know I don't have to do it myself.  What's wrong here?

Comment: same problem, not able to connect to the websocket out side of the rails application.